# Get all latitudes and longitudes between source and destination coordinates in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to retrieve all latitudes and longitudes between source and destination coordinates.I know that we can easily create a path between source and destination coordinates but i want all the latitudes and longitudes between them for the purpose of user movement.I am using MkMapView to show the coordinates and CLLocationManager to retrieve the current location.I am new in iPhone.I searched for this question but i did not get accurate results.Please help me.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want the latitudes and longitudes that correspond to screen coordinates in the map view?  Otherwise, latitudes and longitudes are just numbers - you can add and subtract them, although you need to account for the discontinuity between 180 and -180 longitude

Comment: No i want the exact coordinates between source and destination coordinates.suppose my current location is delhi and if i search noida gps will give me the path.for user movement tracking i need all latitudes and longitudes between delhi and noida

Comment: Do you mean the latitudes and longitudes of points on a route between the two locations?

Comment: yes,the latitudes and longitudes of points on a route between the two locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a high school algebra problem.  If you have point A and point B (in your views coordinate system) then you can find an equation that describes the line between the two.  You'll mostly likely want to use the point slope formula.  Once you have an equation that describes the line then you can find all points between them, however there are an infinite number of points on the line.  You'll have to decide the level of of accuracy you want.  Anyways a simple loop from point A's X to point B's X, evaluating the equation and solving for Y at each iteration should yield you a set of points.  You can then use the convertPoint method from MKMapView to get a lat and long.

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view
```

Edit: Update with a concrete example

This is assuming you have a mkMapview instance someplace.  This probably should go inside of your mapview.  If you need more explanation you might want to check out mathisfun.com http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html

```
MKMapView mapView.... //this is your job to intialize, this code probably belongs inside
//your mapview so should probably be assigned to self. 

//Point slope formula: y - y1 = m*(x - x1)
//m = x-x1 / y - y1

//two points from a line that starts at 0,0 and goes diagonlly up to the right at a 45 degree angle
CGPoint pointA = CGPointMake(0, 0);
CGPoint pointB = CGPointMake(10, 10);

//find the slope
CGFloat m = (pointB.y - pointA.y) / (pointB.x - pointA.x);

NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = pointA.x; i <= pointB.x; i++)
{
    //for each x value between A and B use the point slope formula to find the y value
    //since were starting at pointA (0, 0) our equation becomes
    //y - 0 = m * (x - 0), simplifying and solving for y we get
    //y = m * (x - 0) -> y = m*x, and since we are increment x each time our equatio we evaluate is
    // y = m*i
    CGFloat y = m*i;

    CGPoint c = CGPointMake(i, y);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mapView convertPoint:c toCoordinateFromView:self.view];

    //for simplicity in adding to the array I convert to a CLLocation object since an NSArray can only hold objects
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
    [points addObject:location];
}
```

Comment: can you give me a proper code.

Comment: updated with an example.  If this is for something like a school assignment please cite this post in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MKDirections API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKDirections) to obtain routing information, but it doesn't return the individual latitude and longitudes for the steps in the route.  It will return a series of steps which are navigation instructions and `MKPolyLines` that can be overlaid on an `MKMapView`